# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, react

Eu estava fazendo um projeto e nele pedia para usar uma "key", eu coloquei ela e dava sempre o erro de `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`, então eu olhei o stack overflow pra ver mais e percebi que a key deveria ser única, dei um console.log, porem o resultado era de números diferentes e um erro

Código:

```
    <div className="page">
      <section className="lists">
        {movieList.map((item, key) => (
          <div>
            {item.name}
            <MovieRow key={key}/>
            
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  )
```

segue `console.log(key)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o `Key` ai é na `div`

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro você ler o tópico da [documentação do React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) para obter mais detalhes mas irei deixar o trecho pertinente ao seu problema.

> `key` é um atributo string especial que você precisa definir ao criar listas de elementos.

O atributo `key` deve ser único e aplicado ao componente pai de cada iteração.

```
<div className="page">
  <section className="lists">
    {movieList.map((item, key) => (
      <div key={key.toString()}>
        {item.name}
        <MovieRow />
      </div>
    ))}
  </section>
</div>
```